# How to get hover captions on images in Ishimoto

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hover, squarespace

I am working on my graduate thesis project's website on squarespace (I'm a documentary photographer) and I'm having a big issue with the caption options with this template. As of now the caption information goes directly on top of the image. My project has to be written in Spanish and English, so with all of that text half of my images are covered. Is there some kind of squarespace CSS injection that would hide these captions until someone hovered over the image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the title attribute on the image.

```
<img src="/url to image/" title="put your caption here" alt="put your alternate text here (if user cannot view the image)">
```

Comment: Sorry CSS is new to me. So should I enter that into the squarespace CSS box? And when enter my caption into the title section of the image information?
I guess simply, where am I putting that code and where do I enter the caption/.

Comment: Also, when I enter that CSS in the box it says that there is a syntax error?

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to ignore my previous answer as that was a general HTML method but not specific to Squarespace. In Squarespace what you want to do is select your image and click 'Edit'.

Click 'Edit' again and directly below the thumbnail image you should have a dropdown menu. Select the 'Caption Overlay on hover' option. Now write in your caption on the image. Click Save, then exit. Now it will only appear on hover.